# How can I tell if a function is a monotonic transformation?

Tags: functions

In my Economics class, we are talking about monotonic transformations of ordered sets.  But I don't understand how I can tell if a given function will preserve the order.

**My Question**

What determines whether a function is monotonic and how do I show it is?

Also, if someone could help me understand what the difference is between a function and transformation that would be great because I think I am misusing terminology.

Comment: "The words map or mapping, transformation, correspondence, and operator are often used synonymously." P. Halmos, Naive Set Theory (1970).

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are partially ordered sets with orders $\leq_{A}$
and $\leq_{B}$, a monotone function $f\colon A\rightarrow B$
satisfies the following: whenever $x,y\in A$ with $x\leq_{A}y$, we have $f\left(x\right)\leq_{B}f\left(y\right)$.

For example, if $A=B=\left[0,\infty\right)$ with the usual order
on the real line, then $x\mapsto x^{2}$ is a monotone function. Can
you use the above definition to show that this is true?

Comment: More precisely, that would be a *monotone increasing* function (replace the $\leq_B$ with $\geq_B$ for *monotone decreasing*).

Comment: That's a good point. Some sources define "monotone preserving" or "monotone" as what you call "monotone increasing."

Comment: Given $a \leq b$, then $a^2 \leq ba \leq b^2$? Does that make sense?

Comment: That is correct.